# Using HTML over canvas, nothing has worked

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to get my OVERLAY tag to appear on top of my canvas javascript. I've gone through all the questions on here but nothing has worked!

Please help! Code:

page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
            <script src="test-script.js"></script>
            <div id='overlay'>OVERLAY
                <br></br>
                OVERLAY
                <br></br>
                OVERLAY
            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
#canvas {position: fixed; z-index: -1;}
#overlay {margin-top: -50px; z-index:0; position: relative;}
```

test-script.js

```
var ns = ns || {};

(function draw() {
    var c;
    var ctx;
    var trails = [];

    document.body.onload = function() {
        c = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );

        c.width     = 2000;
        c.height    = 2000;

        document.body.appendChild( c );
        ctx = c.getContext( "2d" );

        trails.push( new ns.trailer( [990000, 990000, 990000, 600000, 600000 ]));
        // trails.push( new ns.trailer( [  600000,600000,600000,600000,600000,600000,600000  ] ));
        trails.push( new ns.trailer( [  8000000, 8000000, 8000000, 990000, 990000 ] ));

        document.onmousedown = reset;
        reset();
        setInterval( compute, 0 );

    }

    function reset() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect( 0,0,c.width,c.height );
        for( var i =0; i < trails.length; i++ ) {
            trails[ i ].reset();
        }
    }

    function compute() {
        for( var i =0; i < trails.length; i++ ) {
            trails[ i ].compute( ctx );
        }
    }
})();

ns.trailer = function( colors ) {
    this.points = [];
    this.stroke = new ns.stroke( null, 100, 10, colors[ 0 ] );

    this.colorIterator = 10;
    this.colors = colors;
}

ns.trailer.prototype = {
    reset : function() {
        this.points = [];

        this.width = document.body.offsetWidth;
        this.height = document.body.offsetHeight;

        this.radius = Math.max( this.width, this.height ); 
        this.center = new ns.point( this.width / 2, this.height / 2 );

        this.a0 = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
        this.a1 = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
        this.a2 = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;

        var mul = 1 + Math.random() * 2;

       if( Math.random() > .5 ) mul *= 5;
       else mul /= 2;

       this.s0 = ( Math.random() - .5 ) * mul / 180 * Math.PI;
       this.s1 = ( Math.random() - .5 ) * mul / 180 * Math.PI;
       this.s2 = ( Math.random() - .5 ) * mul / 180 * Math.PI;
    },
    compute : function( ctx ) {
        with( this ) {
            a0 += s0;
            a1 += s1;
            a2 += s2;

            var c = Math.cos( a0 ) * Math.cos( a1 ) * Math.cos( a2 );
            var s = Math.sin( a0 ) * Math.sin( a1 ) * Math.sin( a2 );
            points.push( new ns.point( center.x + c * radius,
                                 center.y + s * radius  )  );

            if( points.length > 10 ) points.shift();

            stroke.anchors = points;
            stroke.draw( ctx );

            var t = .5 + (Math.sin( new Date().getTime() * .001 ) * .5 );
            stroke.color = colors[ Math.floor( t * colors.length ) ];
            stroke.width = 25 + ( 1 - t )  * 50;
            //stroke.strokeCount = 5 + t * 5;
            stroke.strokeCount = 5;
        }
    }
}

ns.point = function( x,y ) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

ns.point.prototype = {
    add : function( p ) {
        return new ns.point( this.x + p.x, this.y + p.y );
    }.
    sub : function( p ) {
        return new ns.point( this.x - p.x, this.y - p.y );
    },
    negate : function() {
        this.x *= -1;
        this.y *= -1;
        return this;
    },
    clone : function() {
        return new ns.point( this.x, this.y );
    },
    length : function() {
        return Math.sqrt( this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y );
    },
    normalize : function ( scale ) {
        scale = scale || 1;
        var l = this.length();
        this.x /= l;
        this.x *= scale;
        this.y /= l;
        this.y *= scale;
        return this;
    }
}

ns.stroke = function( anchors, width, strokeCount, color ) {
    this.anchors = anchors;
    this.width = width;
    this.strokeCount = strokeCount;
    this.color = color;
}

ns.stroke.prototype = {
    normal : function( p0, p1 ){    
        return new ns.point( -( p1.y - p0.y ), (    p1.x   - p0.x ) );   
    },
    draw : function( ctx ) {
        if( this.anchors == undefined ) return;

        var half = this.height * .5;
        var p, c, n, pnorm, pln, prn, cnorm, cln, crn;

        with( this ) {
            for( var j = 0; j < strokeCount; j++ ) {
                half = width * .5 * Math.random();
                var col = ns.variation( color, 35 );
                ctx.lineWidth = .1 + Math.random() * 2;

                for( var i = 0; i < anchors.length - 2; i++ ) {
                    p = anchors[ i ];
                    c = anchors[ i+1 ];
                    n = anchors[ i+2 ];

                    pnorm = normal( p, c );
                    cnorm = normal( c, n );

                    half += ( Math.random() - .5 );
                    pnorm.normalize( half );
                    pln = p.add( pnorm );

                    pnorm.normalize( -half );
                    prn = p.add( pnorm );

                    half += ( Math.random() - .5 );
                    cnorm.normalize( half );
                    cln = c.add( cnorm );

                    cnorm.normalize( -half );
                    crn = c.add( cnorm );

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
                    ctx.moveTo( prn.x, prn.y );
                    ctx.lineTo( crn.x, crn.y );
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.closePath();

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
                    ctx.moveTo( pln.x, pln.y );
                    ctx.lineTo( cln.x, cln.y );
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.closePath();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

ns.variation = function( color, amount ) {
    amount = amount || 25;
    var r = color >> 16 & 0xFF;
    var g = color >> 8 & 0xFF;
    var b = color & 0xFF;

    r += Math.floor( ( Math.random() - .5 ) * amount );
    g += Math.floor( ( Math.random() - .5 ) * amount );
    b += Math.floor( ( Math.random() - .5 ) * amount );

    r = r > 0xFF ? 0xFF : r < 0 ? 0 : r;
    g = g > 0xFF ? 0xFF : g < 0 ? 0 : g;
    b = b > 0xFF ? 0xFF : b < 0 ? 0 : b;

    return "rgba("+r+','+g+','+b+','+Math.random()+');';
}
```

**I've added my Javascript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `absolute` position. Also mention width and height to `100%`. `z-index` should be higher to place element over other elements.

```css
  #canvas {
    position: fixed;
  }
  #overlay {
    z-index: 9;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
  <div id='overlay'>OVERLAY
    <br>OVERLAY
    <br>OVERLAY
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried with no luck... I've added my javascript. Maybe its a problem with that?

Comment: Yes it works fine - it just won't let my put the div over it

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:150px;
  z-index:10;
}
```

Adjust the "top" and "left" amounts to get OVERLAY positioned on top of the canvas.

It was the JavaScript.

Run my code snippet.

```js
var ns = ns || {};

(function draw() {
    var c;
    var ctx;
    var trails = [];

    document.body.onload = function() {
        c = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );

        c.width     = 2000;
        c.height    = 2000;

        document.body.appendChild( c );
        ctx = c.getContext( "2d" );

        trails.push( new ns.trailer( [990000, 990000, 990000, 600000, 600000 ]));
        // trails.push( new ns.trailer( [  600000,600000,600000,600000,600000,600000,600000  ] ));
        trails.push( new ns.trailer( [  8000000, 8000000, 8000000, 990000, 990000 ] ));

        document.onmousedown = reset;
        reset();
        setInterval( compute, 0 );

    };

    function reset() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect( 0,0,c.width,c.height );
        for( var i =0; i < trails.length; i++ ) {
            trails[ i ].reset();
        }
    }

    function compute() {
        for( var i =0; i < trails.length; i++ ) {
            trails[ i ].compute( ctx );
        }
    }
})();

ns.trailer = function( colors ) {
    this.points = [];
    this.stroke = new ns.stroke( null, 100, 10, colors[ 0 ] );

    this.colorIterator = 10;
    this.colors = colors;
};

ns.trailer.prototype = {
    reset : function() {
        this.points = [];

        this.width = document.body.offsetWidth;
        this.height = document.body.offsetHeight;

        this.radius = Math.max( this.width, this.height ); 
        this.center = new ns.point( this.width / 2, this.height / 2 );

        this.a0 = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
        this.a1 = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
        this.a2 = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;

        var mul = 1 + Math.random() * 2;

       if( Math.random() > .5 ) mul *= 5;
       else mul /= 2;

       this.s0 = ( Math.random() - .5 ) * mul / 180 * Math.PI;
       this.s1 = ( Math.random() - .5 ) * mul / 180 * Math.PI;
       this.s2 = ( Math.random() - .5 ) * mul / 180 * Math.PI;
    },
    compute : function( ctx ) {
        with( this ) {
            a0 += s0;
            a1 += s1;
            a2 += s2;

            var c = Math.cos( a0 ) * Math.cos( a1 ) * Math.cos( a2 );
            var s = Math.sin( a0 ) * Math.sin( a1 ) * Math.sin( a2 );
            points.push( new ns.point( center.x + c * radius,
                                 center.y + s * radius  )  );

            if( points.length > 10 ) points.shift();

            stroke.anchors = points;
            stroke.draw( ctx );

            var t = .5 + (Math.sin( new Date().getTime() * .001 ) * .5 );
            stroke.color = colors[ Math.floor( t * colors.length ) ];
            stroke.width = 25 + ( 1 - t )  * 50;
            //stroke.strokeCount = 5 + t * 5;
            stroke.strokeCount = 5;
        }
    }
};

ns.point = function( x,y ) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

ns.point.prototype = {
    add : function( p ) {
        return new ns.point( this.x + p.x, this.y + p.y );
    },
    sub : function( p ) {
        return new ns.point( this.x - p.x, this.y - p.y );
    },
    negate : function() {
        this.x *= -1;
        this.y *= -1;
        return this;
    },
    clone : function() {
        return new ns.point( this.x, this.y );
    },
    length : function() {
        return Math.sqrt( this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y );
    },
    normalize : function ( scale ) {
        scale = scale || 1;
        var l = this.length();
        this.x /= l;
        this.x *= scale;
        this.y /= l;
        this.y *= scale;
        return this;
    }
};

ns.stroke = function( anchors, width, strokeCount, color ) {
    this.anchors = anchors;
    this.width = width;
    this.strokeCount = strokeCount;
    this.color = color;
};

ns.stroke.prototype = {
    normal : function( p0, p1 ){    
        return new ns.point( -( p1.y - p0.y ), (    p1.x   - p0.x ) );   
    },
    draw : function( ctx ) {
        if( this.anchors === undefined ) return;

        var half = this.height * .5;
        var p, c, n, pnorm, pln, prn, cnorm, cln, crn;

        with( this ) {
            for( var j = 0; j < strokeCount; j++ ) {
                half = width * .5 * Math.random();
                var col = ns.variation( color, 35 );
                ctx.lineWidth = .1 + Math.random() * 2;

                for( var i = 0; i < anchors.length - 2; i++ ) {
                    p = anchors[ i ];
                    c = anchors[ i+1 ];
                    n = anchors[ i+2 ];

                    pnorm = normal( p, c );
                    cnorm = normal( c, n );

                    half += ( Math.random() - .5 );
                    pnorm.normalize( half );
                    pln = p.add( pnorm );

                    pnorm.normalize( -half );
                    prn = p.add( pnorm );

                    half += ( Math.random() - .5 );
                    cnorm.normalize( half );
                    cln = c.add( cnorm );

                    cnorm.normalize( -half );
                    crn = c.add( cnorm );

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
                    ctx.moveTo( prn.x, prn.y );
                    ctx.lineTo( crn.x, crn.y );
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.closePath();

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
                    ctx.moveTo( pln.x, pln.y );
                    ctx.lineTo( cln.x, cln.y );
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.closePath();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

ns.variation = function( color, amount ) {
    amount = amount || 25;
    var r = color && 16 && 0xFF;
    var g = color && 8 && 0xFF;
    var b = color && 0xFF;

    r += Math.floor( ( Math.random() - .5 ) * amount );
    g += Math.floor( ( Math.random() - .5 ) * amount );
    b += Math.floor( ( Math.random() - .5 ) * amount );

    r = r > 0xFF ? 0xFF : r < 0 ? 0 : r;
    g = g > 0xFF ? 0xFF : g < 0 ? 0 : g;
    b = b > 0xFF ? 0xFF : b < 0 ? 0 : b;

    return "rgba("+r+','+g+','+b+','+Math.random()+');';
};
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:150px;
  z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id='container'>
  <div id='overlay'>
   <h1>
    OVERLAY
   </h1>
  </div>
  <canvas id='canvas'>
  </canvas>
 </div> 
  <!-- scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test-script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that. No luck as it still won't put the div on top. Instead 'OVERLAY' just appears in a footer at the bottom  that doesn't have the javascript running over it

Comment: I am looking at this on my computer now, i'll take a closer look.

Comment: @ronaldmurphy just to make sure I understand correctly, do you want your canvas to write out the word OVERLAY or, have OVERLAY appear on top of the canvas?

Comment: have OVERLAY appear on top of the canvas

Comment: Any ideas? I've run out of options :/

Comment: I just edited my answer. Let me know if that helped. :)

Comment: No luck, overlay is now appearing at the top (no matter how I set 'top' and 'left') and its not on the top of the canvas... did you try on your computer?

Comment: Yes I was able to get the position on top of the canvas. :/

Comment: Where is the location of your Javascript file?

Comment: @ronaldmurphy I got it working, look at my code snippet. Change the c.width and c.height as needed. I think you could get rid of them and do the height and width in the HTML markup and then the drawing will happen in the canvas rather on the entire DOM.

Comment: Thanks! Why does it work in the code snippet yet when i select my html folder on my comp it still doesn't work?

Comment: What IDE are you using and what is your folder setup look like?